# RethinkDB operator precedence

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

Does anyone knows Rethinkdb operator precedence?

e.g.

```
doc('x1').mul(doc('x2')).add(doc('x3')).mul(doc('x4'))
```

is equivalent to

```
(x1 * x2) + (x3 * x4)
```

or

```
x1 * (x2 + (x3 * x4))
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just going to do each one sequentially (no precedence rules) so your statement should evaluate to:

```
((x1 * x2) + x3) * x4
```

If you want to accomplish the first of your examples try:

```
doc('x1').mul(doc('x2')).add(doc('x3').mul(doc('x4')))
```

If you want to accomplish the second of your examples try:

```
doc('x1').mul(doc('x2').add(doc('x3').mul(doc('x4'))))
```